# Access the value of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image: Image of the Console]

I am working with a function that returns a value to a variable. When i console log the variable it shows what your seen in the image. i need to get access to the value so I can display it to the user how can i do this?

this is my code
    function save(user)
        {

```
        var response= Restangular.all('admin').post(user).then(function (postedUser) {

            return postedUser;

        });

        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What is your js code? And any relevant html code?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reponse` is a **promise**. You can't (or should not be able to) access the value of a promises directly, since the promise might not be resolved yet.

Instead, you have to pass a callback to the promise. When the promise is resolved with a value, it passes that value to all attached callbacks. In your example, the promise will *eventually* be resolved with value of `postedUser`.

The function that calls `save` can access the value like so:

```
save(...).then(function(value) {
  // do something with value here
});
```

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) [about promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

---

Note: You can drop the `.then` inside the function and simplify it to

```
function save(user) {
    return Restangular.all('admin').post(user);
}
```

since you are passing the identity function to `.then`.